# Can I check in to TFS from CLI with a work item association?

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I can attempt to check in to TFS, but I get a policy violation because it isn't associated with a work item. That's fine, I do that all the time in VS, but I'm trying to do it via the command line and I can't figure out how to associate the `tf vc checkin` with a work item. Is this possible?

This is using tf CLI v14, VS 2015, TFS 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done from CLI, but you can however use the override parameter to override the checkin policy:

/override:(reason|@reasonfile)

Overrides a check-in policy using one of the following arguments:

• reason: A user-provided reason why the check-in policy is being ignored.

• Reasonfile: The path to a file that contains a user-provided description of the reason why the check-in policy is being ignored.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx